# ES6 * Typescript : Cannot find namespace

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

Node7.4.0 / ES6 / Typescript 2.1.5 / WebStorm 2016.3

On the line :
    **export default heroRoutes.router;**

I get:  **TS2503 Cannot find namespace 'heroRoutes'**
after creating it and init()
what could be wrong with it ?

thanks for feedback

> HeroRouter.ts

```
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
const Heroes = require('../data');

export class HeroRouter {
    router: Router;

    /**
     * Initialize the HeroRouter
     */
    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();
        this.init();
    }

    /**
     * GET all Heroes.
     */
    public  getAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        res.send(Heroes);
    }

    /**
     * GET one hero by id
     */
    public getOne(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        let query = parseInt(req.params.id);
        let hero = Heroes.find(hero => hero.id === query);
        if (hero) {
            res.status(200)
                .send({
                    message: 'Success',
                    status: res.status,
                    hero
                });
        }
        else {
            res.status(404)
                .send({
                    message: 'No hero found with the given id.',
                    status: res.status
                });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Take each handler, and attach to one of the Express.Router's
     * endpoints.
     */
    init() {
        this.router.get('/', this.getAll);
        this.router.get('/:id', this.getOne);
    }

}

// Create the HeroRouter, and export its configured Express.Router
let heroRoutes = new HeroRouter();
heroRoutes.init();

export default heroRoutes.router;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const heroRouter = new HeroRouter();
const router = heroRouter.router;
export default router;
```

The reason for this is that you cannot export a qualified name.
The exports of a module are bound to a special object known as the module namespace object. One reason is that if qualified exports were legal, the semantics would be surprising as updating the value of the instance member `router` of the variable `heroRouter` would not update the value of the exported binding (here named `default`).

Comment: thanks Aluan , that's the point ! I should also not forget to insert the heroRouter.init() between the two const  declarations...

what's the point here ? is it in the export default parameter ...
any link to some doc ?...

Comment: Indeed there's a bit of context missing, I updated my answer

Comment: As for the `init` method, I would get rid of it and put all the logic in the constructor. It is a bad practice to allow objects to be created in an invalid state. It leads to bugs, like the one in my example in the context of your question.

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpful comments... 
can it be rewritten as :
const heroRouter = new HeroRouter().router;
export default heroRouter;

Comment: Yes if you drop the init method or make it chain the instance and call it.