# error TS2503: Cannot find my namespace

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I am running *tsc --watch* (compiling typescript into javascript) and catching warning:

```
router/PostRouter.ts(103,16): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'postRoutes'.
```

In my .ts file in the 103 string:

```
const postRoutes = new PostRouter();
postRoutes.routes();
export default postRoutes.router;
```

So, what's wrong?

---

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-express-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start:server": "nodemon --watch ./build/index.js",
    "watch:build": "tsc --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "1.18.2",
    "compression": "1.7.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "cors": "2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "5.0.1",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "helmet": "3.12.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.5",
    "mongoose": "5.0.15",
    "morgan": "1.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "1.16.8",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "1.4.1",
    "@types/cors": "2.8.4",
    "@types/express": "4.11.1",
    "@types/mongoose": "4.7.32",
    "@types/node": "9.6.6",
    "nodemon": "1.17.3",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.8.3"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 \* Typescript : Cannot find namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049783/es6-typescript-cannot-find-namespace)

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
const { router } = postRoutes

export default router
```

in `export default postRoutes.router`, TS assumes that `postRoutes` is a namespace.

Comment: Your solution is correct but your explanation is confusing.